# Django form wizard - redirect to first step after done based on a condition

Tags: python, django, forms, wizard

I am pretty new to Django. Here is my problem. I have 3 step form wizard. At the end of 3rd step, I need to process the data (by calling an API). If the result of the call is True, I need to redirect the user to a page that displays the data from all steps of the wizard (summarized). If the result is False, then I need to redirect the user to a page where a message will be shown...something like "API call failed, you need to re-enter the information again" and add a button that redirects the user to the first step of the wizard HAVING ALL PREVIOUSLY ENTERED DATA in it.

I can show the summarized in a page when the result is TRUE. But I don't know how to show a page that allows user to go back to the step 1 of the form with previously entered data intact.

I have one template for all the three forms.

Please note that I simplified the code a little bit to make it short.

```py
forms.py
--------

class Step1Form(forms.Form): def init(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    super().init(*args, **kwargs) questions = 
    Question.objects.filter(object_type_id=1) 
    self = add_form_fields(self,questions) ##This is my method where I am adding fields based on some logic

class Step2Form(forms.Form): def init(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    super().init(*args, **kwargs) 
    questions = Question.objects.filter(object_type_id=10) 
    self = add_form_fields(self,questions)

class Step3Form(forms.Form): def init(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    super().init(*args, **kwargs) 
    questions = Question.objects.filter(object_type_id=20) 
    self = add_form_fields(self,questions)


views.py
--------

class MyQuestionWizard(SessionWizardView): 
    template_name = 'question.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return self.render(self.get_form())
        except KeyError:
            return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)


    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        form_data = process_form_data(form_list)

        return render_to_response('done.html',{'form_data': form_data})

question.html (One template for all forms)
-------------------------------------------

{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% block head %}
{{ wizard.form.media }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
        <form action="" method="post" class="f1" novalidate>{% csrf_token %}
        <h3>Provide context about your data</h3>
        <p>Complete the required and optional questions below</p>
        {{ wizard.management_form }}
        {% for hidden_field in form.hidden_fields %}
                {{ hidden_field }}
        {% endfor %}
        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                <div class="form-group" align="left">
                {% if field.field.required %}
                    <label for="{{ field.auto_id }}" class="required">{{ field.label }}</label>
                {% else %}
                    <label for="{{ field.auto_id }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
                {% endif %}
                {% render_field field  %}
                {% if field.help_text %}
                     <label class="help-text">{{ field.help_text }}</label>
                {% endif %}
                </div>
        {% endfor %}

        <br>

        {% if wizard.steps.current == wizard.steps.last %}
            <div class="f1-buttons">
                <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" class="btn btn-previous" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">{% trans "Previous" %}</button>
                <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" class="btn btn-submit" value="submit">{% trans "Submit" %}</button>
            </div>
        {% elif wizard.steps.prev %}
            <div class="f1-buttons">
                <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" class="btn btn-previous" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">{% trans "Previous" %}</button>
                <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" class="btn btn-next" value="{% trans "submit" %}">{% trans "Next" %}</button>
            </div>
        {% else %}
            <div class="f1-buttons">
                <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" class="btn btn-next" value="{% trans "submit" %}">{% trans "Next" %}</button>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        <p align="center"> Step {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} of {{ wizard.steps.count }} </p>
        </form>
{% endblock %}

urls.py
---------

from .views import MyQuestionWizard
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from .forms import Step1Form, Step2Form, Step3Form

from django.contrib import admin
urlpatterns = [
    #path('', views.introView),
    url(r'^myquestion/', MyQuestionWizard.as_view([("step1", Step1Form),
             ("step2", Step2Form),
             ("step3", Step3Form)])),
]
```

### done.html

This will be the result page (not included in the Wizard). I want this page to show:

1) If result from processing the data is TRUE: Summarized view of the data

2) If result from processing the data is FALSE: 
I want to show a message to user, to update their entries 
and show a button that redirects the user to the first step of the wizard,
with all previously entered data intact.

```
I don't know how to do this.
```

Comment: Do you have a template? Are the 3 forms in the same page?

Comment: Yes, I have one template for all the 3 forms.

Comment: I have updated the post and added the template used for all the forms

Comment: Why don't you show the fail message in the same page/template? That way you will have the data in the form. I would use AJAX.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about using the same page/template for the fail message. I don't know AJAX. Is there no way to do it in Django?

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is to reload the wizard template with you validated form in the template context if the API call is `False`. Something like this:

```
class MyQuestionWizard(SessionWizardView): 
    template_name = 'question.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return self.render(self.get_form())
        except KeyError:
            return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)


    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        form_data = process_form_data(form_list)

        # If the form is not valid
        # Your template should reload the page setting the form already filled
        return render_to_response('question.html', {
            'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
        })

        # If the form is valid
        return render_to_response('done.html',{'form_data': form_data})
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question. I am updated the post with urls.py code. Is that what you are asking? Could you please clarify? 

I was thinking may be I should write the done method like this:

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        form_data = process_form_data(form_list)
        form = DoneForm(initial={<create dictionary of the fields used in DoneForm>})
        return render(self.request, 'done.html', {'form':form})

Comment: Check my updated answer. You have to reload the view with the wizard 1 data form filled.

Comment: Thanks Hagyn for your quick reply. I tried that and I have two issues.

1) When form is not valid, and I am redirecting to question.html like you mentioned above, I am getting an empty wizard without any form fields. How can we fix this?

2) Before redirecting, I want to tell users that validation failed, that's why they are being redirected. Is it possible to do that? Or we can have a label of something in 'question.html' and this label will get activated ONLY when it wizard loads from a redirection. Is it possible like that?

Comment: I checked that form_data has all required data when the render_to_response is called for question.html. But, still, nothing is displayed.

Comment: Any help on this? Thanks in advance.